# Avoiding multiple inner joins to add new column (info) from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm wondering if there is a way to bring `name` information for `user_id`, `sender_user_id` and `recipient_user_id` from the schema in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce11b/1).

The only way I can think of now is to do this nested inner join, which I feel like is inefficient:

```
SELECT e.id
    ,msg_owner
    ,msg_owner_name
    ,sender_user_id
    ,sender_name
    ,recipient_user_id
    ,f.NAME AS recipient_name
    ,msg_body
    ,created_at
FROM (
    SELECT c.id
        ,msg_owner
        ,msg_owner_name
        ,sender_user_id
        ,d.NAME AS sender_name
        ,recipient_user_id
        ,msg_body
        ,created_at
    FROM (
        SELECT a.id
            ,user_id AS msg_owner
            ,NAME AS msg_owner_name
            ,sender_user_id
            ,recipient_user_id
            ,msg_body
            ,created_at
        FROM messages AS a
        INNER JOIN users AS b ON a.user_id = b.id
        ) AS c
    INNER JOIN users AS d ON c.sender_user_id = d.id
    ) AS e
INNER JOIN users AS f ON e.recipient_user_id = f.id
```

Is there any (more efficient) way to bring in `name` values for each of the aforementioned three columns? Thank you for your answers/suggestions!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your multiple inner joins.  It's perfectly normal and correct.  The only change I would make is that you don't need three nested selects.  `SELECT a.id, b.id, c.id FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.a = b.x INNER JOIN c ON a.b = c.y` works fine...

Comment: Can you post a table of what you want the result to look like, given the sample input tables? Since you have no nested aggregate groups, this whole thing can mostly likely be done without any nested SELECTs, using joins all at the same level instead.

Comment: @MatBailie Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Mike, I thought SQLFiddle would have saved my sample (desired) table, but it didn't. But as you might be able to tell from the query in my question, I was trying to bring the 'name' information from [users] table to three different column. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use joins, not nested joins.

Your way, you force the database to gather back all the results of each inner query, and then having it join to another table. Unless the contents of the inner most query are very limited via a WHERE clause, this will always be bad for performance.

Below is the proper way to use joins. It allows direct use of indexes (if present) to speed things up.

```
SELECT m.id
    ,owner.id AS msg_owner
    ,owner.name AS msg_owner_name
    ,m.sender_user_id
    ,sender.name AS sender_name
    ,m.recipient_user_id
    ,recipient.name AS recipient_name
    ,m.body AS msg_body
    ,m.created_at
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN users sender
ON sender.id = m.sender_user_id
INNER JOIN users recipient
ON recipient.id = m.recipient_user_id
INNER JOIN users owner
ON owner.id = m.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer along with a detailed explanation. Mureinik's answer is also what I was looking for, but I would accept yours as the "right" one because it is slightly more informative. Thank you!

Comment: @onedaywhen Comparing the `EXPLAIN` plan in SQLFiddle for each query, you can see a difference. However, you are correct, it doesn't necessarily query the innermost rows first. In every situation I've experienced, when someone creates a query like the OP's, it performs significantly worse than doing a straight forward join. See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html. I'll update my answer later (work calls), detailing how the `ref` and `ALL` in the OP's explain plan mean the performance is worse than the `eq_ref` in my query's explain plan.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `join` clauses on the same query without any need for nesting. I'm not sure, offhand, if this will improve performance or not, but at the very least it would make the query less cumbersome:

```
SELECT m.id,
       m.user_id AS msg_owner,
       o.name AS msg_owner_name,
       m.sender_user_id,
       s.name,
       m.recipient_user_id,
       r.name AS recipient_name,
       m.body,
       m.created_at
FROM   messages m
JOIN   users o ON m.user_id = o.id
JOIN   users s ON m.sender_user_id = s.id
JOIN   users r ON m.recipient_user_id = r.id
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds.

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you for answering my question! I now know it possible to user many `INNER JOIN`s like that. I accepted Willem's answer because he explained a bit more about the performance and thought it might be useful for other SQL beginners like me. :)